# Left join to get most recent entries

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have the tables `users` and `statuses` . I want to select all the users, plus any statuses they might have, but only the most recent status from each user.

Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
SELECT users.id, alias, gender, login, logout, users.create_date, statustext as statustxt, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birthdate,CURDATE()) AS age
                FROM users
                LEFT JOIN statuses s ON users.id = s.user_id
                WHERE s.ID = (                              
                        SELECT MAX(s2.ID)                    
                        FROM statuses s2
                        WHERE s2.user_id = s.user_id         
                        )
```

This gets the users with the most recent statuses, but not the users from the users table as well. Maybe it can be fixed by some small adjustment?

I got the sub query by searching, but I don't understand how that code works. It seems to compare two versions of the same table (For example: `WHERE s2.user_id = s.user_id` ) . Where can I read about this sort of technique? 
Is a sub query required in this case by the way?

If you can find a solution would be great, and some basic explanation of how it works would highly appreciated.

----------EDIT---------------

I took one of the responses (by maresa) and combined with the sub query of my initial code , and this works(!) It has 3 selects and looks a bit over complicated maybe?:

```
 SELECT users.id, alias, gender, login, logout, users.create_date, statustext as statustxt, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birthdate,CURDATE()) AS age
FROM users
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT user_id, statustext FROM statuses s
         WHERE s.ID = (                             
           SELECT MAX(s2.ID)                
           FROM statuses s2
           WHERE s2.user_id = s.user_id
     )
  ) as s ON users.id = s.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered similar problem. This post is relevant: http://www.microshell.com/database/sql/optimizing-sql-that-selects-the-maxminetc-from-a-group/.

Regarding your specific query, since you care only the latest status, you want to first get the latest status from each users. Assuming that the latest status has the latest id (based on your sample), the SQL would be below:

```
SELECT
    MAX(ID), statustext, user_id
FROM
    statuses
GROUP BY
    user_id
```

What the above query does is, to get the latest status per user_id. Once you get that, you can think of it as if it's a table. Then simply join on this "table" (the query) instead of the real one (statuses table). Therefore, your query would be like below:

```
SELECT
    users.id, alias, gender, login, logout, users.create_date, statustext as statustxt, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birthdate,CURDATE()) AS age
FROM
    users
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            MAX(ID), user_id
        FROM
            statuses
        GROUP BY
            user_id
    ) as s ON users.id = s.user_id
    LEFT JOIN statuses ON statuses.ID = s.ID -- EDIT: Added this line.
```

Comment: Great, I get all users plus one status with those who have statuses , BUT  your first query gives the latest status ID while the "statustext" is actually the one which belongs to the earliest ID..strange.

Comment: I combined your code with the sub query I had, which made it work (added it to my post)

Comment: Ah yeah. I forgot to add another join to statuses table. Please check if it's working now. My code is much better than yours as yours has dependent sub-query and could be expensive if you have a lot of rows in table. If your table is not large, it doesn't matter. but if it is, you could be looking at 10-minute query vs 24-second query.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a subselect as the join, and limit to show only 1 row:

```
SELECT 
    users.id, 
    alias, 
    gender, 
    login, 
    logout, 
    users.create_date, 
    statustext as statustxt, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birthdate,CURDATE()) AS age
FROM users
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id,statustext 
    FROM statuses s1
    WHERE s1.user_id = users.id
    ORDER BY status_date DESC
    LIMIT 1
) s ON users.id = s.user_id
```

Comment: I get "Unknown column 'users.id' in 'where clause' "

Answer (score 0):

You could use a in clause with a tuple

```
SELECT 
      users.id
    , alias
    , gender
    , login
    , logout
    , users.create_date
    , statustext as statustxt
    , TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birthdate,CURDATE()) AS age
  FROM users
  LEFT JOIN statuses s ON users.id = s.user_id
  WHERE (s.user_id, s.ID)  in  (                              
          SELECT user_id, MAX(s2.ID)                    
          FROM statuses s2
          group by user_id       
  )
```

Comment: This gives me the same result as my original query, the recent statuses but not the other users.

Comment: then update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  .. please